# How to retro style texturing?? (like megaman legends)

Tags: texturing, uv, workflow

I found a texturing style I really like and would like some insight in order to work on it:
Is there a typical way to approach this texturing? Do I export the UV layout to photoshop
and apply the coloring in a small canvas? Do I use the texture paint mode in order to have
a more clear idea of what is where and then take it to photoshop?
How do you plan the UV layout to be optimized?
How would you do this? [image]

Comment: you can use a super pixellated image texture if this is what you mean, you need to choose the good mode in the Image Texture node though

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you'd have to use seams where you want your UV's to be seperated (right click - add seam) and then UV unwrap it and position the UV Islands how you want. (you can export the UV lay out in the UV editor under the UV tab)

for texturing you can use photoshop or texture paint. But make sure that you use a small image size and when using the image in the shader editor to use closest texture interpolation if you want a pixelated texture or linear if you want a more muddy look.

[image: where you can find image interpolation]

I'd say render it out in a higher resolution and then down scale it like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQcovwUHMf0